# Gradle mavenDeployer - how to include a separate modules code

Tags: java, jar, gradle

I have a project like this:

> MyProject
>    |-ModuleA
>    |-ModuleB

Module A is an Android Library that creates an aar, it has a dependency on Module B like so:

```
 dependencies {
   compile project(':ModuleB')
```

In ModuleA I am using `mavenDepoyer` to release locally:

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories.mavenDeployer {
        pom.groupId = "com.foo"
        pom.artifactId = "bar"
        pom.version = "1.0"
        repository(url: "file://${localReleaseDest}")
    }
}
```

This generates me an `AAR` file and a `POM`.

When uncompressed the `AAR` **does not contain** the class files from Module B
and the `POM` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
  <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>aar</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>MyProject</groupId>
      <artifactId>ModuleB</artifactId>
      <version>unspecified</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

As you can see this declares that the `AAR` has a dependency on ModuleB with an unspecified version. And so if I use this this `AAR/POM` as a remote, it fails to resolve the dependency ModuleB.

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':example'.
 Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':example:_debugCompile'.
    Could not find MyProject:ModuleB:unspecified.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/MyProject/ModuleB/unspecified/ModuleB-unspecified.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/MyProject/ModuleB/unspecified/ModuleB-unspecified.jar
     Required by:
         Test:example:unspecified > com.foo:MyProject:1.0
```

**I do not want it to try and resolve Module B as another dependency, I want to use the mavenDeployer to be able to create the `AAR` & `POM` with Module B included inside, since I have the source code here to do that!**

---

Searched the web to no avail, these sites gave hints but no answer:

[How to publish apks to the Maven Central with gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19833612/how-to-publish-apks-to-the-maven-central-with-gradle)

[how to tell gradle to build and upload archives of dependent projects to local maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847758/how-to-tell-gradle-to-build-and-upload-archives-of-dependent-projects-to-local-m)

http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_management.html

http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sub:multiple_artifacts_per_project

http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#deployerConfig

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, AARs don't include their dependencies (only APKs do). Instead, transitive dependency resolution will take care of resolving not only the AAR but also its dependencies. The unspecified version is most likely a result of not setting the `project.version` property in ModuleB.

Comment: So if I uploaded the generated aar & pom to maven central I would also have to upload the `ModuleB` jar separately for it to be resolved? Seems like I should just use a single module to avoid the hassle ...

Comment: Yes, that's how it's normally done. There *might* be a way to include ModuleB in the AAR, but I don't know any details on that, and I don't think it's the norm. (It certainly isn't in Java land.) Instead of publishing to Maven Central, you could also publish to your own [Bintray](https://bintray.com/) repository (which, once it gets included in JCenter, also gets synced to Maven Central).

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>MyProject</groupId>
  <artifactId>ModuleB</artifactId>
  <version>unspecified</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

The reason is your module dependencies is below :

```
compile project(':module B')
```

to resolve this issue, you should dependens maven dep
compile 'com.xxxxxx.xxx:xxxxx:1.0.0-SHNAPSHOT'

Comment: you sure about adding dependency to a '-SNAPSHOT' library? Snapshots are development builds, not official releases....

Comment: I mean, it depencies code, not an aar, and ignore the snapshot I wrote.

Comment: "I mean, it depencies code, not an aar, and ignore the snapshot I wrote." - can you rephrase your comment? I did not understand you.

Comment: Lead to Maven POM file occur <version>unspecified</version>, the reason is in gradle file dependencies closure not  specified version，before i made a mistake :  api project(':xxxxxx'), so maven deployer dosenot exact generate POM file unless : api "group_name:module_name:version_name"